# How do I simplify my code into just one module?

Tags: verilog

I am not sure how to simplify this code so it only instantiates seg7 once. I am new to verilog so i have no clue.The current code runs fine, I just need to know how to simplify it. If you all could be kind enough to look at the code tell me what I need to do that would be gladly appreciated.

```
module Design (SW, HEX0,HEX1,HEX2,HEX3);
    input [3:0]SW;
    output [0:6]HEX0;
    output [0:6]HEX1;
    output [0:6]HEX2;
    output [0:6]HEX3;

    seg7hex3 disp1(SW[3:0],HEX3);
    seg7hex2 disp2(SW[3:0],HEX2);
    seg7hex1 disp3(SW[3:0],HEX1);
    seg7hex0 disp4(SW[3:0],HEX0);
endmodule

module seg7hex3(bcd,leds);
    input [3:0] bcd;
    output reg[1:7] leds;

    always @(bcd)
        case(bcd) //abcdefg
            0: leds = 7'b0000000; // b1111111 for active high (B)
            1: leds = 7'b0110001; // b1001110 (C)
            3: leds = 7'b0000000; // b1111111 (B)
            4: leds = 7'b0100100; // b1011011 (S)
            5: leds = 7'b0001111; // b1110000 (-)
            6: leds = 7'b0100100; // b1011011 (S)
            default: leds =7'bx;
    endcase

endmodule

module seg7hex2(bcd,leds);
    input [3:0] bcd;
    output reg[1:7] leds;

    always @(bcd)
        case(bcd) //abcdefg
            0: leds = 7'b0001000; // b1110111 for active high (A)
            1: leds = 7'b1001000; // b0110111 (H)
            3: leds = 7'b0110000; // b1001111 (E)
            4: leds = 7'b0000001; // b1111110 (O)
            5: leds = 7'b0111001; // b1000110 (|)
            6: leds = 7'b0000001; // b1111110 (O)
            default: leds =7'bx;
    endcase

endmodule

module seg7hex1(bcd,leds);
    input [3:0] bcd;
    output reg[1:7] leds;

    always @(bcd)
        case(bcd) //abcdefg
            0: leds = 7'b1110001; // b0001110 for active high (L)
            1: leds = 7'b1111001; // b0000110 (I)
            3: leds = 7'b0110000; // b1001111 (E)
            4: leds = 7'b0111000; // b1000111 (F)
            5: leds = 7'b1110001; // b0001110 ( first edge half V)
            6: leds = 7'b1000010; // b0111101 (d)
            default: leds =7'bx;
    endcase

endmodule

module seg7hex0(bcd,leds);
    input [3:0] bcd;
    output reg[1:7] leds;

    always @(bcd)
        case(bcd) //abcdefg
            0: leds = 7'b1110001; // b0001110 for active high (L)
            1: leds = 7'b0011000; // b1100111 (P)
            3: leds = 7'b0001000; // b1110111 (R)
            4: leds = 7'b0001000; // b1110111(A)
            5: leds = 7'b1000111; // b0111000 (back edge half V)
            6: leds = 7'b0001000; // b1110111 (A)
            default: leds =7'bx;
    endcase

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

How about putting all always blocks in one module (see below)? Here is the link at [edaplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/44Q). Looks like you are passing the same bcd value to all se7hex modules, so rather than four bcd inputs, you can simplify my code even more by only having one bcd input and changing all always blocks to always @(bcd).

```
module Design (SW, HEX0,HEX1,HEX2,HEX3);
input [3:0]SW;
output [0:6]HEX0;
output [0:6]HEX1;
output [0:6]HEX2;
output [0:6]HEX3;

seg7hex3_0  disp_1_4 (
            SW[3:0],HEX3,
            SW[3:0],HEX2,
            SW[3:0],HEX1,
            SW[3:0],HEX0
            );
endmodule

module seg7hex3_0(
            bcd1,leds1, 
            bcd2,leds2, 
            bcd3,leds3, 
            bcd4,leds4
            );
input [3:0] bcd1, bcd2, bcd3, bcd4;
output reg[1:7] leds1, leds2, leds3, leds4 ;

always @(bcd1)
    case(bcd1) //abcdefg
        0: leds1 = 7'b0000000; // b1111111 for active high (B)
        1: leds1 = 7'b0110001; // b1001110 (C)
        3: leds1 = 7'b0000000; // b1111111 (B)
        4: leds1 = 7'b0100100; // b1011011 (S)
        5: leds1 = 7'b0001111; // b1110000 (-)
        6: leds1 = 7'b0100100; // b1011011 (S)
        default: leds1 =7'bx;
endcase

always @(bcd2)
    case(bcd2) //abcdefg
        0: leds2 = 7'b0001000; // b1110111 for active high (A)
        1: leds2 = 7'b1001000; // b0110111 (H)
        3: leds2 = 7'b0110000; // b1001111 (E)
        4: leds2 = 7'b0000001; // b1111110 (O)
        5: leds2 = 7'b0111001; // b1000110 (|)
        6: leds2 = 7'b0000001; // b1111110 (O)
        default: leds2 =7'bx;
endcase

always @(bcd3)
    case(bcd3) //abcdefg
        0: leds3 = 7'b1110001; // b0001110 for active high (L)
        1: leds3 = 7'b1111001; // b0000110 (I)
        3: leds3 = 7'b0110000; // b1001111 (E)
        4: leds3 = 7'b0111000; // b1000111 (F)
        5: leds3 = 7'b1110001; // b0001110 ( first edge half V)
        6: leds3 = 7'b1000010; // b0111101 (d)
        default: leds3 =7'bx;
endcase

always @(bcd4)
    case(bcd4) //abcdefg
        0: leds4 = 7'b1110001; // b0001110 for active high (L)
        1: leds4 = 7'b0011000; // b1100111 (P)
        3: leds4 = 7'b0001000; // b1110111 (R)
        4: leds4 = 7'b0001000; // b1110111(A)
        5: leds4 = 7'b1000111; // b0111000 (back edge half V)
        6: leds4 = 7'b0001000; // b1110111 (A)
        default: leds4 =7'bx;
endcase

endmodule
```

If you only have one bcd input, you can also combine all cases in one always block:

```
always @(bcd)
    case(bcd) //abcdefg
            0: begin
                leds1 = 7'b0000000; // b1111111 for active high (B)
                leds2 = 7'b0001000; // b1110111 for active high (A)
                leds3 = 7'b1110001; // b0001110 for active high (L)
                leds4 = 7'b1110001; // b0001110 for active high (L)\
            end
            1: begin
                ...
            end
            ...
    endcase
```

Comment: I would also recommend changing the hard coded outputs to parameters to make is easier to read and change in the future.  For example `parameter B = 7'b0000000;` `parameter C = 7'b1001110;` and then you can write `0: leds1 = B;` `1: leds1 = C;`.  In the future if your display changes you can change the parameters in one place.